# Ingest data from Kafka Topics to Redshift with upserts

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect

I need help to ingest data from Kafka topics (created by postgres Kafka Source Connector) and insert/update/delete on Redshift sink.

I read about the Redshift Sink Connector by Confluent, but it doesn't support update (upsert) operation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the JDBC sink with the Redshift JDBC driver?

Comment: It doesn't work. If I choose to use PostgresDialect and insert.mode = upsert, it tries to run the command "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ON CONFLICT ..." and I get an SQL Exception because of "ON CONFLICT" command isn't supported on Redshift.

Comment: Even am also facing same error, Do we have any solution to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating separate connectors for each record operation?
For example:

- 1 sink connector to handle INSERTs ("insert.mode": "insert")
- 1 sink connector to handle UPDATEs ("insert.mode": "update")
- 1 sink connector to handle DELETEs ("insert.mode": "insert", "delete.enabled": "true")

Use this pattern for each table you want data streamed into Redshift.
I know this sounds weird and not that much efficient, but it will allow you to use the Generic dialect and avoid using UPSERT mode (which is not supported by Redshift at all).
I'm not 100% sure this works for you, I'm trying it here and it looks promising so far. But again, not sure if this will fit in your situation. Hope it helps.