# Tombstones per Update query for redshift sink connector?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Goal: Sync data between MySQL and Redshift via redshift sink connector and debezium cdc source connector

Exploring [Redshift Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/aws-redshift/current/overview.html)

We're able to see inserts and deletes queries in mysql being achieved in redshift table, here's the configs for both -

**rs sink properties**

```
pk.mode=record_key
insert.mode=insert
auto.create=true

delete.enabled=true

tasks.max=1

schema.context=default
```

**dbz properties**

```
tombstones.on.delete=true
after.state.only=true


topic.cleanup.policy=delete

transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones=false`
```

But, given insert.mode does not support upsert, `UPDATE` queries are seen as new rows in redshift. Which is undesirable.

Confluent support mentioned

> We have a feature request opened for allowing deletes by the connector but currently there is no ETA for the same(FF-7002). Upserts will also not work, and there is another feature request for the same(FF-10649)

Can delete + insert be implemented?

Is there a transformation logic that can be configured s.t for any `UPDATE` query, cdc connector sends two events - 1 tombstone (for the key, which gets deleted in rs) + 1 insert (after state)?

I understand this [was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115329/ingest-data-from-kafka-topics-to-redshift-with-upserts) asked before, however want to first try a single connector, if possible